# Is there CSS support for "inherit" in IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

Is there any possible way to get CSS support in IE7 for "display:inherit"?

I tried using [ie7.js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/) but it did not seem to help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried using ie7.js but it did not seem to help...

Of course it's not going to help. IE7.js makes IE6 and earlier behave like IE7. A script that makes a browser act like IE7 is not going to be very useful to IE7 itself.

`inherit` is only supported starting from IE8. So, you'll want IE8.js and not IE7.js.

Comment: ie7.js is just the name of the project, however, it has IE7-9 upgrade support. If you check the project page, you can see this. I used the IE8 upgrade of ie7.js which upgrades MSIE5.5-7 to be compatible with MSIE8.

Comment: Exactly. It wasn't clear which of the scripts you were using. As far as I know IE8.js and IE9.js provide `inherit` support.